# How to add right click Print option to libreoffice files in Nautilus

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, printing

I was wondering if it could be added to the right click menu an option to "print" the file without the need to open it and then print it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Once potential solution is to use *nautilus-actions* to create a right-click menu option in nautilus.

Unfortunately, the version in oneiric causes a segmentation fault.  One good third-party PPA you could use is described in this answer.

An alternative is to download the [32bit or 64bit .deb package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-actions/3.1.4-1) from the precise repository and install this (`sudo dpkg -i [deb-package-name].deb`)

**to install**

Copy and paste line by line the following in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dr3mro/nautilus-actions-extra
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions
```

Now launch the config tool:

```
nautilus-actions-config-tool
```

Create a new action called *Libreoffice Print*

[image]

Then enter the the command `libreoffice` with the parameters `-p %F` as per this image.

**Hint:** If you want't you can enter `-p %M` instead and select *Appears if selection has multiple files or folders*. Then you can select and print multiple files.

**Another Hint:** You might want to ristrict the entry to LibreOffice files. So enter **.odt* as filename condition.

[image]

**nautilus refresh**

Although I'm not not sure why - if you install the package `nautilus-refresh` then the nautilus-actions sub-menu  is combined with the standard right-click menu option as per the first image in this answer.

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-refresh
```

Save. Run the following for the new menu option to take effect.

```
nautilus -q
```

Comment: A you've been little bit faster than me... ;) Exactly the same solution. But I used %M instead of %f.

Comment: :) many thanks for the extra tip - its a good one!

Comment: Yeah, but you'll get the full bounty! Unfair! ;)   But another detail: I think you should uncheck "Display item in location context menu". This is the menu when you click on folders, right? With folders it's not working. You'd have to add some kind of wild card maybe.