# How to rename an application so as to affect alphabetical order of right-click "open with" applications list?

Tags: nautilus, rename, nautilus-actions, context-menu

I've recently switched my default pdf viewer from **acroread** to **qpdfview**; for (serious, duplex-multipage) ***printing***, though, I still prefer **Evince** (to both acroread and qpdfview).

To quickly open a pdf with Evince, I used to be able to

1. open the **context-menu** (by right-clicking, <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>f10</kbd> or the context-menu button),
2. followed by <kbd>h</kbd> for "Open wit_**h**_" and
3. finally <kbd>Enter</kbd>, to open Evince, which then *was* the **first entry** in the applications list.

Now, however, acroread leads the alphabetical list; hence, I need to use the <kbd>down</kbd> or <kbd>up</kbd> key(s) to select Evince *before* hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I'd like to ***rename*** acroread (whilst keeping it in that very list) to, say, **z**_acroread, so Evince would come up as the first entry again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `acroread` has a `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications`, you could simply make a back up and then sudo (or gksudo) edit that file and change the name to `z_acroread` or whatever. Alternatively, you could copy the `.desktop` file over to `~/.local/share/applications` and change the name in the copied file and not in the original without the need for sudo. That way, only the specific user will see the difference.

In other words, look for a line that begins with `Name=`. That would be the one to change from `acroread` to `z_acroread`.

Comment: funny, did sth very similar just the other day: made geany use gedits icon... by the very same method!

Comment: If I could, I'd accept both answers... how? http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5282/can-i-accept-two-answers-on-a-question/5285#5285

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a better solution is to use Nautilus Actions to create a right-click menu option in Nautilus.

Install with:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions
```

and follow the instructions given in [this article on adding new functions to the context menu](http://shuffleos.com/1784/nautilus-actions-add-new-functions-nautilus-context-menus/) and/or in the [answer to this question on adding a print command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86322/how-to-add-right-click-print-option-to-libreoffice-files-in-nautilus).

**Note**: That question is from 2011, so probably you should try installing from the repositories first (as indicated above).

Then you would create an option to open (or, better, **print**) with Evince.

Good luck.

Comment: sounds great; I'll leave the question open for now, though, as I'd also be interested in the "renaming-solution", though your suggestion might prove to be even more elegant and efficient. Thanks!